# How to populate data in OrderEntryData

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I added one attribute in AbstractOrderEntryModel, but I want to populate this attribute in OrderEntryData. I added just a new property in OrderEntryData but it's not working.

So to get this in OrderEnryData do we have to write separate populator for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new attribute in extension-beans.xml. Below code will add the new attribute to the existing OrderEntryData bean.

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.data.OrderEntryData">
    <property name="newAttribute" type="Integer"/>
</bean>
```

You will also need to create a new Populator (see `de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.converters.populator.OrderEntryPopulator` for reference), and add the populator to the converter via customextenstion-spring.xml.

```
<bean id="customOrderEntryPopulator" class="com.chang.populators.CustomOrderEntryPopulator" />

<bean parent="modifyPopulatorList">
    <property name="list" ref="orderEntryConverter"/>
    <property name="add" ref="customOrderEntryPopulator"/>
</bean>
```

**Other references:**

- Converters and Populators: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/8b937ff886691014815fcd31ff1de47a.html
- ModifyPopulatorList: https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/1905/en-US/45fab1996cba43ed97a62cac3f58d46d.html